# A Spin up particle in QFT

Tags: quantum-field-theory, mathematical-physics, field-theory, foundations, hilbert-space

This appears like a question that is rarely addressed in field theory pedagogy (perhaps because the answer is obvious): **how does one describe a particle of definite spin in quantum field theory?**

For example, given some state in a theory of spinors (say a single particle for simplicity): $|\psi\rangle = \int \psi(p) a^\dagger(p)|p\rangle$, where $a$ is the ladder operator you obtain by canonically quantizing, say a Dirac field. Since this is a Dirac field, it describes a particle of spin 1/2. **How does one extract information about the spin of this particle?**. For example, what would the creation operator for a single particle of definite spin up look like?

Comment: What do you mean, "Without knowing anything about its position or momentum"? *Then you don't know the state!* (and thus cannot create it)

Comment: For example, in non-relativistic quantum mechanics, I can write down something like $|0\rangle$, and say this is a state of spin up. This alone doesn't contain any information about its linear momentum, right?

Comment: Because, when you write down the spin states as $|0\rangle$ and $|1\rangle$, you *implicitly assume* that the spin degree of freedom is the only degree of freedom the system/particle has. If you are considering a particle that is not trapped at a spot, but free to move in a line, then "spin-up" is certainly not enough to specify its state.

Comment: Exactly and I'm asking if the same can be done in QFT.

Comment: That would mean you have no spatial degrees of freedom, and thus no need for QFT (since it would not differ from QM)!

Comment: You're right, thanks. I have updated the question to reflect what I was trying to get at more precisely, sorry for the ambiguity in the previous version.

Comment: I believe QFT describes how the spin statistics arise. Then you proceed like normal QM to describe the spin dynamics.

Comment: Alright, now your question makes sense :) Unfortunately, it is a bit tedious to answer it, since one has to look carefully at how the spinor rep is constructed and how the mode decomposition of a Dirac field really arises (it is not as easy as saying: Just take the ladder operator). I refer you to the [excellent lecture notes](http://www.thphys.uni-heidelberg.de/~weigand/QFT1-13-14/SkriptQFT1.pdf) of the course I heard on introductory QFT, especially chapters 3.4 - 3.6

Comment: @PhotonicBoom Can you be more explicit in how does one go back to normal QM?  It seems like to do so, one has to take the state created in the QFT, then rewrite it in the tensor product hilbert space of the particle's spacial and angular degrees of freedom, in which case one still needs to extract information about what is the spin of the particle created by the QFT creation operator.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fields in QFT are promoted to operators.

The Dirac field operator describes both a particle (electron) and and a anti-particle (positron), and there exist different creation and anihilation operators for the particle ($a^+_s(p), a_s(p))$ and the anti-particle ($b^+_s(p), b_s(p)$). The subscript $s$ indicates that you are creating or destroying a particle of spin $s$ $(\frac{1}{2}$ or $-\frac{1}{2})$
.

For more details, see in Wikipedia [Dirac fields](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fermionic_field#Dirac_fields).

A particle is described by a state, for instance an electron with definite position and spin, is  described by the state:  $|p,s\rangle = a^+_s(p)|0\rangle$, that is you apply the creation operator $a^+_s(p)$ on the vacuum state $)|0\rangle$

Comment: You're right, s is the spin degree of freedom, I'll have to go over the derivation again. thanks.